# jQuery conditional differed resolving

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, deferred

I have 2 model objects and a view. I use deferred to resolve these.
Now while the view would always be there, I can have either one or both the model objects to resolve depending on the condition.
Below is the code;

```
var self = this,
myDeferred1 = new $.Deferred(),
myDeferred2 = new $.Deferred(),
viewDeferred = new $.Deferred();

if (typeof personId !== "undefined") {
    var myObj1 = new MyObj1({
        attr1  : attrId1,
        attr2   : personId
    });

    myObj1.fetch({
        success: function() {
            myDeferred1.resolve(myObj1);
        }
    });
}

var myObj2 = new MyObj2({
        attr1  : attrId1
    });

myObj2.fetch({
    success: function() {
        myDeferred2.resolve(myObj2);
    }
});


require(['myView'], function(MyView) {
                viewDeferred.resolve(MyView);
            });

$.when(myDeferred1, myDeferred2, viewDeferred).then(function(myObj1, myObj2, MyView) {

});
```

My question is since myDeferred1 would come into picture only conditionally (typeof personId !== "undefined")

how do I check the same when doing

> $.when(myDeferred1, myDeferred2, viewDeferred).then(function(myObj1,
>   myObj2, MyView)

Would I have to replicate the code by doing if ..else...like below OR is there a better way of doing it ?

```
if (typeof personId !== "undefined") {          
    $.when(myDeferred1, myDeferred2, viewDeferred).then(function(myObj1, myObj2, MyView) {
    });         
} else {
    $.when(myDeferred2, viewDeferred).then(function(myObj2, MyView) {
    });         
}
```

Comment: Why not resolve `myDeferred1` regardless of `personId` occurence and handle it by looking at the data returned in your callback?

Comment: @testndtv Is body of `then()` different between `.then(function(myObj1, myObj2, MyView)` and `.then(function(myObj2, MyView)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `else` clause to resolve `myDeferred1` immediately.

```
if (typeof personId !== "undefined") {
    //... as in question
} else {
    myDeferred1.resolve({});
}
```

By resolving with an empty plain object, you can test for `myObj1.attr1` and `myObj1.attr2`, without throwing an error.

For example :

```
$.when(myDeferred1, myDeferred2, viewDeferred).then(function(myObj1, myObj2, MyView) {
    if(myObj1.attr1 && myObj1.attr2) {
        // personId *was not* undefined 
    } else {
        // personId *was* undefined 
    }
});
```

Or, if `personId` is still in scope (and is guaranteed not to have changed during the async activity), then simply test `if(personId !== undefined)` again.